# Excel grouping numbers and letters

Tags: excel

Hi guys i got a strange job to do from my boss today, i have a bunch of records that are part numbers i.e

BC101   my boss wants me to group the BC101 with BC101R together.
problem arrises when i get parts like

BC101

BC1011

BC101R

i need it to be

BC101

BC101R

BC1011

and so on,  theres around 5k parts that needs there "R" counter next to them underneath the record.  Any ideas?

Comment: are all the parts the same amount of characters? Like they will always have a base of 5 characters and then the R or 1?

Comment: nah different length, but always ending in a number or the letter R

Comment: cracked it, i made another column and if R is not on the end then add R1, then group on that column

Comment: Note that you can answer you own question (it is even [highly recommended](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)) and accept it. This way, you can share your knowledge with the community and kind of *close* the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

extra column to the right that does the following.

Pseudo:
 if R is not on the end then add R1, then group on that column